# UIPopoverController permitted arrow directions issues

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

I have an UIPopoverController that has to shows with the arrow direction up, but when I try to show popover in the bottom of view I see this:

[image]

```
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[sender frame] inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Comment: What if you show us some code?

Comment: [sender frame] is my button plus

Comment: i need to figure out how i can check when popover can't shows in full size controller that it contain

Comment: maybe I need some condition in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown` in this case. Since the button is in the bottom area of the view, if you want to show the popover below the button (that is what `UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp` suggests implicitly), it doesn't have any space to show the pop over.

If you use `UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny`, then iOS automatically figures out which way it can extend.

Comment: That's it, @Matrosov confused the arrow direction with the popover position

Comment: thanks yes I understand, but can I check it? I mean - will I show up direction or down if i don't have any space for show it when direction is up?

Comment: so that's means that I need to know when popover can shows normally with direction up and when I need to change this direction to down

Comment: There is no such convenient way AFAIK. I think you need to calculate the space between your button and edge of the view, and compare it with the potential size of your popover view.

Comment: I got confused as well with the arrow direction which is supposed to be the opposite of the pop over direction XD

Answer (score 3):

As **uliwitness** said for multiple directions but updated for Swift 4. try below code:

```
popover.permittedArrowDirections = [.up, .down]
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is new, but the permitted arrow directions are a bit field and can be combined. So you can write `UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown | UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp` and it will pick whichever of the two it has room for.